# Function to turn a matrix into a vector by applying the given operation

Tags: dictionary, scheme, lisp, racket

I am trying to write a function that takes in an operation and a matrix to turn the matrix into a vector. For example if I called `(matrix-to-vector + ((1 2 3 4) (5 6 7 8)))` it would return `(6 8 10 12)` coming from `(1+5 2+6 3+7 4+8)`.The matrix input is an NxM matrix, and the operation is a two argument operator (like + - * / or string-append). It uses the operator to combine the elements of each column of the matrix together, thus returning a vector of size M. I have a feeling map would be helpful here, but I'm not sure how to implement it. I would be mapping the operation to the each element in the columns of the matrix to get the resulting vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `map` will do the trick, as suspected. The only other thing to consider is that you should use `apply`, because the input is a list of lists:

```
(define (matrix-to-vector op lst)
  (apply map op lst))
```

For example:

```
(matrix-to-vector + '((1 2 3 4) (5 6 7 8)))
=> '(6 8 10 12)
```

Comment: So does apply "apply"  map and the operation to each list within the list?

Comment: Yes, in this case, `apply` applies `map` using as parameters the operation and all the sublists. If the sublists weren't inside a list themselves, we could have done this: `(map + '(1 2 3 4) '(5 6 7 8))`. Remember that `map` receives as parameters an operation and one or more lists, if more than one is passed, the operation is applied element-wise over them.

Answer (score 0):

One can also use `'map'` in a simpler manner if one separates the lists making up the matrix:

```
(map + '(1 2 3 4) '(5 6 7 8))
```

Output:

```
'(6 8 10 12)
```

It will also work with more than 2 lists for an N*M matrix:

```
(map + '(1 2 3 4) '(5 6 7 8) '(10 20 30 40))
```

Output:

```
'(16 28 40 52)
```